# Using SSH agent with Docker Compose and Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, ssh, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am having issues using a private github repo in one of my NestJS apps. When I create the docker image using the `docker build` command, the image is successfully created and everything works fine. However I can't use the Dockerfile with `docker-compose`.

Here's the part of `Dockerfile` where I use the `BuildKit` mount feature:

```
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN --mount=type=ssh npm install
```

When building the image with `Dockerfile` alone I pass the `--ssh default` argument, like this and it successfully installs the private repo:

```
docker build --ssh default -t CONTAINER_NAME .
```

Following [this article](https://medium.com/@vanuan/ssh-and-docker-compose-7bce10b67765), inside the `docker-compose.yml` file I have included the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` like this:

```
environment:
      - NODE_ENV:${NODE_ENV}
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK:${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
volumes:
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
```

However I get this error whenever I try to run `docker-compose up`

```
#11 44.97 npm ERR! code 128
#11 44.97 npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
#11 44.97 npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/organization/repo.git
#11 44.97 npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
#11 44.97 npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#11 44.97 npm ERR! 
#11 44.97 npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#11 44.97 npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

They have added the ssh flag as option to the build key in compose: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/pull/234

```yaml
services:
  sample:
    build:
      context: .
      ssh:
        - default
```

Answer (score 9):

Your `environment` syntax is incorrect. The `environment` block can either be a list of `NAME=VALUE` pairs:

```
environment:
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
```

Or it can be a dictionary:

```
environment:
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK: ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
```

Yours is neither of those things, so your container has no `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable.

If I use this `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  ssh:
    image: fedora:35
    environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
    volumes:
      - ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        yum -y install openssh-clients
        sleep inf
```

I can `exec` into the container (after waiting for the package installation to complete) and verify that it is able to talk to my agent:

```
$ docker-compose exec ssh ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:... (RSA)
4096 SHA256:... (RSA)
```

---

Also, one unrelated comment about your `volumes:` block: you're being inconsistent in how you refer to variables. This isn't a problem, but it hurts my brain (and inconsistencies like this can sometimes lead to weird problems in other contexts). You might as well just always use the `${varname}` syntax when referring to environment variables:

```
volumes:
  - ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
```

Comment: it's not working. how do you run the docker build command?

Comment: There is no "docker build" command required in this example; it uses an existing image.

Comment: @cyril just `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to give a more complete answer with the different components involved in the process, also including a GitHub Actions workflow in case someone needs it.

I also made a [gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/fievelk/96edd5da09f6832da1b1ebbfccd98f68) for Python, I'll just adapt it to your scenario here.

- Docker Compose (`docker-compose.yaml`):

  ```yaml
  version: '3.2'

  services:
    my-app:
      platform: linux/amd64
      build:
        ssh:
          - default=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
      command: my-command.sh
  ```
- Dockerfile (just the relevant part):

  ```
  # Add GitHub's SSH host keys to the known hosts and install your dependencies
  RUN --mount=type=ssh mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && \
      ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts && \
      npm install
  ```
- GitHub workflow:

  ```yaml
  name: Build My-App
  on:
    push:
      branches:
        - "*"

  jobs:
    build-test:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      env:
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK: $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
      steps:
        - name: Checkout code
          uses: actions/checkout@v3

        - name: Set up SSH key
          run: |
            mkdir -p ~/.ssh
            ssh-agent -a ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} > /dev/null
            ssh-add - <<< "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}"
        - name: Build docker image
          run: docker compose build my-app
  ```